# Div hides after clicking on any child of this element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a script that when clicked, ejects the div and assigns the active class to the appropriate parent element. I also added functionality that when clicked outside the div dropdown closes it. Unfortunately, by clicking inside the dropdown divider on any element it is also hidden. How can I fix this so that the clickability of items in the middle of the dropdown does not affect it?

```js
$(document).click(function() {
 $("#dropdown").slideUp("fast");
 $(".dropdown-parent").removeClass("active");
});

$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-parent:not(.active)", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".dropdown-parent").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#dropdown").slideDown("fast");
});

$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-parent.active", function() {
 $("#dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
 $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
background: red;
color: #fff;
}

#dropdown {
display: none;
background: black;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test2</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test3</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test4</a>

<div id="dropdown" class="container">
  <a href="#">test in dropdown</a>
  <p style="color: white">test2 in dropdown</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: `deja vu` I see this topic two times today `lol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *stop propagation* of the click inside `.container`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".container", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$(document).click(function() {
 $("#dropdown").slideUp("fast");
 $(".dropdown-parent").removeClass("active");
});

$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-parent:not(.active)", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".dropdown-parent").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#dropdown").slideDown("fast");
});

$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-parent.active", function() {
 $("#dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
 $(this).removeClass("active");
});

$(document).on("click", ".container", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.active {
background: red;
color: #fff;
}

#dropdown {
display: none;
background: black;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test2</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test3</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">test4</a>

<div id="dropdown" class="container">
  <a href="#">test in dropdown</a>
  <p style="color: white">test2 in dropdown</p>  
</div>
```